# Connect with Amazon documentDB & Amazon MQ from Java Service

Tags: java, ssl, truststore, aws-documentdb, amazon-mq

My use case is to connect amazon documentDB to read the change stream & send that change stream event to amazon MQ from same service after deploying it on EKS cluster. I am able to connect with documentDB after reading the keys specified in rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem & importing it into the local trust store through following entries in docker entry point:

```
"-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=*********","-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/app/certs/truststore.jks",
```

After establishing a connection with documentDB & reading change stream (whenever there is insert, replace or delete in collection), I am trying to send the change stream event to amazon MQ through openwire protocol, When I am trying to create a connection with MQ as specified in Amazon MQ documents, I am getting exception

> Could not stablish connection with
> ssl://X-XXXXXXX-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXXXXX-1.mq.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:61617 due to PKIX javax.net.ssl.sslhandshakeexception

I know where the problem is. When I deploy my service without specifying truststore entries in docker entry point for documentDB then it connects with MQ & I am able to send the mock event to MQ too but with documentDB when I specify the truststore then service also looks for certificate for MQ in truststore which is actually not required for MQ as it is managed by AWS. We don't need to specify truststore & keystore with Amazon MQ.

My question is then how I can connect with Amazon documentDB & Amazon MQ from same service? My requirement is to read the change stream event from documentDB & send it to amazon MQ from same service. I am using a simple java service but open to convert it into spring boot if there is some concrete solution available.

I tried searching for any pem file for MQ which I can use in similar way like documentDB but as I mentioned earlier that Amazon MQ is managed service for Active MQ so there is no pem file available.

Can someone please suggest some solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I resolved this issue by adding certs explicitly to my local trust store required to establish connection with AWS services.

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to use documentDB and Amazon MQ you need to add both lists of certificates

1. Document DB - follow the instructions here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/connect_programmatically.html
2. Add Starfield certificate, you can find the link here - https://www.amazontrust.com/repository/

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Links to other websites should always be helpful, but avoid making it necessary to click on them as much as possible.  You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).